# REST API - GET Request filter by Ids

Tags: rest, api, http, httpwebresponse

Let's say I have an index endpoint to list units
`GET /projects/1/units/?id[]=1,2,3`

and units with ids(1,2) belongs to project with id (1) but unit with id (3) doesn't belong to this project

What should be the proper response for this case, please note it's `GET` collection endpoint.

Response should be `200` with list of available units or `400` Bad Request because the unit with id=3 doesn't belong to the project?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the request really. If the completeness/ integrity of the result is important, then you should return a 404. Else, you can find some way to return the result e.g. a json `{1: Person(...), 2: Person(...)}`. This way, the client will get only what is available and know what is not.

Comment: REST's weakness is in the support of batch requests. As [Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s) pointed out, HTTP, the underlying transport protocol of REST, is an application protocol for the transfer of documents over the Web. Any business rules you trigger are just a side effect of the actual document management. There are techniques like RestQL and GraphQL, though they are more RPC than REST as they have a-priori knowledge on the underlying resource which leads to failures if either the URI structure or the content changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST doesn't say anything about searching or the ability to retrieve multiple things in one API call. Remember that REST APIs should use hypermedia to indicate their state. This means that you can have an API that lists the units for a particular project as links.

```
GET /projects/1/units

{
  'self': {...}
  'links': [
    {
      'rel': 'unit',
      'href': '/projects/1/unit/1',
      'type': 'project.unit'
    },
    {
      'rel': 'unit',
      'href': '/projects/1/unit/2',
      'type': 'project.unit'
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that if unit 3 doesn't exist as part of project 1 then you should be returning a http status 404.

Comment: The idea that I use this query parameter as a filter, let's say the output should be with ids [1,2,4] but I want to filter ids [1,2,3]...but id = 3 doesn't really belong to the dataset because it's not part of project 1...still think that 404 should be the proper output and not returning any data at all?

Comment: IMO it is debatable whether a 404 or a 200 with only the available resources should be returned. In general, REST doesn't promote such concepts as they simply bypass one of the constraints REST has in the name of caching. Such a filtering might be comparable to a traditional search on google or the like where you enter your search terms and get results based on your search terms. If one of the search terms is not known to google, will it return a 404 or serve you with what it has available for the remaining search terms? The same concept may apply here, thus 404 is an opinionated solution IMO